# Web Browser Certificate Enrollment (CSR Generation) and Certificate Download to Smartcard or USB Token

Tags: certificates, public-key-infrastructure, certificate-authority, digital-signature, csr

I am developing Web Application for Certifying Authority as a part of which, I need to generate asymmetric key pair - Private Key and Public Key in user's smartcard through browser, create Certificate Signing Request (CSR) and send CSR to Certifying Authority server, where user's certificate gets generated. Then CA Server will send user's certificate to browser which needs to be downloaded to user's SmartCard or USB Token through browser. How to achieve the same using JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclosure: I work for CISPL, Co. which developes Signer.Digital Browser Extension

Browser Extension may be used to Enroll Certificate (Generate CSR) and Download Certificate in Windows Certificate Store or Smartcard or USB Token from modern browsers. Browser extension provides JavaScript API which in turn talks to host application running on local machine to do the required operations in smartcard and returns response to JavaScript (or says users web page).

CSR generated using Browser Javascript API *genCSR* may be posted to CA Server for certificate generation or to your server if you want self signed certificate. Certificate and Trust Certificate chain received back from the server may be passed to *ImportCer* to import in the certificate store, smartcard or usb token.

API Available for Certifying Authorities in [Signer.Digital](https://download.cnet.com/Signer-Digital-Chrome-Extension/3000-33362_4-78042540.html) Browser Extension are:

1. **Detect connected smartcard:** (Autodetect connected Smartcard or USB Token)

`SignerDigital.getPCSCReaders(onlyConnected = true)`  //List PCSC Readers, set paramater to false if you want to list all available readers

Example:

```
try 
{
    var SmartcardReaders = await SignerDigital.getPCSCReaders();
    var SCReaders = JSON.parse(SmartcardReaders);
    console.log(SmartcardReaders);
    console.log(SCReaders.length);
    if (SCReaders.length > 0)
    {
        $("#selSmartcard").empty();     //selSmartcard is HTML dropdown selector
        for (var i = 0; i < SCReaders.length; i++) {
            //ReaderNames are cryptic, convert to user friendly smartcard name
            var SCName = SignerDigital.getSCNameByReaderName(SCReaders[i]);  //Map PCSC ReaderName to User friendly smartcard name
            $("#selSmartcard").append(new Option(SCName));
        }
        
        //If Windows, add "Windows Certificate Store"
        if (SignerDigital.OSName == "Windows")
            $("#selSmartcard").append(new Option("Windows Certificate Store"));

        $('#selSmartcard option:eq(1)')
    }
}
catch (ErrorMsg) {
    alert(ErrorMsg);
}
```

2. **Generate CSR:** (for Certificate Enrollment in Cert Store, Smartcard or USB Token)

`SignerDigital.genCSR(PKCS11Lib, certSubject, certIssuer, keyBits = 2048, hasgAlgorithm = "SHA256", forceUserPinChangeIfDefault = false, , extensions = null)`

To enforce password policy, viz. force user to change default password set by Smartcard manufacturer, set *forceUserPinChangeIfDefault* to *true*

Sample **extensions** parameter values:

{"SubjectAlternativeName":"RFC822Name=cisplapp@gmail.com"}
{"SubjectAlternativeName":"DNSName=signer.digital;DNSName=charteredinfo.com;DNSName=multidomaincert.test"}
{"SubjectAlternativeName":"URI=https://web.signer.digital;URI=https://help.signer.digital"}

3. **Import / Download Certificate** (Import User Certificate and Trust Certificate Chain to Cert Store, Smartcard or USB Token)

`SignerDigital.importCer(PKCS11Lib, b64Payload, certIssuer)`

```
//Json Model for *b64Payload* param above is: (Base64 of Json of below model)
public class ImportCertReq
{
    public string UserCertB64 ;     //May be null to just import Trust Chain
    public List<string> TrustChainB64;  //May be null to just import USer Certificate
}

//Json Model for success Response from *importCer* promise is:
public class ImportCertResp
{
    public bool IsSuccessUserCertImport;
    public string UserCertImportOutcome; 
    public int TrustChainImportCount; 
    public string TrustChainImportOutcome; 
}
```

*Generate CSR* and *Import Certificate* api uses PKCS#11 library of smartcard or usb token for combability across OS. Thus, requires smartcard drivers to be installed on user's windows pc before using these JavaScript API. For using Windows Certificate Store, pass PKCS11Lib as "Microsoft Enhanced RSA and AES Cryptographic Provider".

Other useful properties and methods in Signer.Digital Extension

4. `SignerDigital.getHostDetails()`

   //Check for property SDHostVersion >= 2 from the response of getHostDetails
5. SignerDigital.OSName
6. SignerDigital.OSSupported
7. SignerDigital.getPkcsLibByProvider(ProviderName)
8. SignerDigital.getSCNameByReaderName(ReaderName)  //ReaderName obtained using promise getPCSCReaders() as listed in point 1 above.
9. SignerDigital.getPkcsLibBySCName(SCName)

You may refer to [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63173083/9659885) for other Certificate, Signing and Encryption/Decryption JavaScript APIs. These API uses Windows CSP and on Linux uses PKCS#11.

Above API may be tested live [Here](https://web.signer.digital/CertDownload)

### Signer.Digital Generate CSR and Download Certificate Flow

[image: Signer.Digital Browser Generate CSR and Download Certificate Flow]